# is there a limit when sending push notifications to multiple iOS devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications

So, I have about 1000 iOS users installed my app.
I tried to send push notification to these users thru my app's backend panel, however, my devices did not receive the push notification. I also asked some users, and some of them said they did receive the push notification and some did not.

I was wondering why not all of the 1000 iOS users receive the push notification successfully. 
At first, I thought it has to do with my applications, because my device has the latest update that is yet to release to public. So I went on and delete all the device tokens I got, and register my device again to test the push notification.

This time, my device received the push notification from backend panel successfully. So, I am sure there is nothing wrong with the coding part on receiving push notifications. (I ran multiple test on this and sure that push are send and receive successfully)

It only happens when I tried to send bulk push notifications to iOS users.

so, is sending push notification has a limit? like it only allows to send may be to 100 users? 
or may be there are invalid device token so that pushes are stopped before finish sending to all users? but in what situation device token become invalid? will uninstalled user's device token may be a cause?

Comment: You’ll have to share quite a few more details about your setup, including whether you are sending silent notifications or regular ones, how you send the notifications (including which version of the protocol, whether you correctly keep the connection open or close and reopen for each notification), what feedback you receive from Apple, etc. There is no limit on the number of notifications, but there are many possible issues that may affect delivery.

Answer (score 1):

In our experience notifications have far from a 100% delivery rate, and that's with only between 50 and a 100 installs across iOS. In theory there is no cap set in place.

The only limits I'm aware of is sending an identical notification to the same device multiple times within a short window of time.