# Limits on silent push notifications per hour

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to understand what is the limit for push notification per hour assuming I do not show the user a message, only update data on a terminated app, to ***move some small critical calculation from a server to the phone***.

So for example if I want to update a device on a value that's being changing all the time, and say I want to inform the phone on a new value every 1-3 minutes , or even 10 minutes, wake up and calculate something and decide if I should alert the user.

Reading many posts like [is there a limit when sending push notifications to multiple iOS devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911244/is-there-a-limit-when-sending-push-notifications-to-multiple-ios-devices)

did not provide a clear answer.
Is it something popular to inform a device every 10M ? is it a good practice ? do large companies do that ?

Comment: There really is no limitation on how often you can send notifications.  Sending to multiple devices, would only be limited by the amount your server is able to handle.

Comment: So Apple do not put any limit ? it is strange because it affects user experience, it affects battery life without the user even knowing about it, etc. Do companies update device so ofter usually ?

Comment: Also, just to clarify, if the user has terminated the app, then the background push isn't delivered to the app.  If the app is just suspended then it will be.

Comment: In addition to what [Paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11) mentioned, a user has the option to disable notifications and/or choose how they should be delivered. If you are sending lots of notifications then you might consider allowing the user to decide how often they receive them; really though the frequency at which you mention is actually quite low — some messaging apps can send notifications every couple of seconds, which can no doubt quickly get annoying.

Comment: @Paulw11 what you said is strange, because my Whatsup and my Messenger are terminated all the time(closed, not in the background), and I do get notifications all the time. Sounds wrong.

Comment: @ l'L'l I said silent notification which means user don't see anything, only the phone get notified and keep the data.\

Comment: They are voip apps so they can use Pushkit. This will relaunch a terminated app

Comment: voip pushes are only for calls with social ID. They wake the app also for messages.

Comment: @Curnelious i missed the “silent” part of your question.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that here :

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_updates_to_your_app_silently

Apple says you allowed to send 2 *Silent Notifications* per hour, and it works only when the app is in the background.

When you send real push notification which inform the user on the lock screen, then you can send how many you like (which is pretty strange because both use the same resources from Apple exactly, and on silent notification I even provide better user experience by filtering some of the notification from alerting him, so its not clear why when the user is being alerted you can spam him but when a server update an app in the background - you have a limit )

Comment: "so its not clear why when the user is being alerted you can spam him but when a server update an app in the background - you have a limit " --> to save battery

Comment: because the user sees the normal notification and can disable the notification if he is spammed!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Remote Notification (silent notification) you have a limit per hour maximum 3 notification you can receive or send.
[Silent Notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app?language=objc).
If you want to update your app in background or even if it is killed, without limitation of Push, you can use [UNNotificationServiceExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension?language=objc) in order to download something from your serve or you can implement some value to share with your main app, then when user open your app, you can refresh it.

Comment: I am seeing only 3 background notifications per day not per hour.  Has the limit changed?

Comment: No, I suggest you to use UNNotificationServiceExtension .